Matplotlib button instabilities, warning
I am writing mass spec data reduction software and am offering the user a button to toggle a subplot between two different data sets.
Before, when I was using matplotlib.pyplot, I didn't have any problems, but now using matplotlib.figure (for compatibility with tkinter), two new problems have cropped up:

UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so results might be incorrect. This is directly related to the button, since without it the error goes away.
Rapidly toggling the button, followed by moving the mouse away from the button, then back over the button, causes the program to hang.

Here is a basic example:
import random
import mplcursors
import customtkinter as ctk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# create the window and frames
window       = ctk.CTk()
data_frame   = ctk.CTkFrame(window)
button_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(window)
data_frame.pack(side=ctk.TOP)
button_frame.pack(side=ctk.BOTTOM)

# lines to plot
lines = {}

# Create the figure and subplots
fig = Figure(figsize=(13, 9), tight_layout=True)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=data_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=ctk.TOP, fill=ctk.BOTH, expand=True)
axes = fig.subplots(2, 2)

# Create some sample data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = {}
y_new = {}
for i in range(1, 101):
    y[i]     = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(len(x))]
    y_new[i] = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(len(x))]

# create a boolean var for toggling between y and y_new in 1,1
show_y_new = ctk.BooleanVar(False)

# Plot the normal data on each subplot
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(1, 101):
            line, = axes[i, j].plot(x, y[k], label=f'Line {k}')
            lines[line] = line
                
# Create a cursor for hover indicators
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(lines, hover=True)
cursor.connect("add")
def on_hover(sel):
    x, y = sel.target
    sel.annotation.set_text(f"({x:.2f}, {y:.2f})")

# create a button to toggle the 1,1 subplot between y and y_new
def on_click(cursor):
    show_y_new.set(not show_y_new.get())
    if show_y_new.get():
        for line in lines:
            if line.axes == axes[1, 1]:
                line.set_ydata(y_new[int(line.get_label().split(' ')[1])])
    else:
        for line in lines:
            if line.axes == axes[1, 1]:
                line.set_ydata(y[int(line.get_label().split(' ')[1])])
            
    valid_lines = [line for line in lines.values() if line.figure is not None]
    canvas.draw()
    cursor.remove()
    cursor = mplcursors.cursor(valid_lines, hover=True)
    cursor.connect("add", on_hover)

# Create the toggle button
global button # do not remove-prevents garbage collection
button_axes = fig.add_axes([0.8885, 0.467, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(button_axes, label='Toggle 1,1 data')
button.on_clicked(lambda event: on_click(cursor))

# create the exit button
exit_button = ctk.CTkButton(window, text='Exit', command=window.destroy)
exit_button.pack(side='bottom')  # add the exit button to the window

# Show the plot
canvas.draw()
window.mainloop()

Note that I am using 100 plots per subplot to represent the large amount of data that can be present on a single plot in my program.
How can I get rid of, or at least suppress, the warning message? And why does moving the mouse away from, then back over, the button cause the program to become unstable?
Edit: In case it's relevant, this is Python 3.7.9 with matplotlib v5.3.5

Was this one solved here? https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/28319

As of about 5 minutes ago, yes. There were two problems: the cursor needed to be global (currently looking for a more elegant solution) as it wasn't being cleared and was creating multiple hovers when the plot was toggled. The second solution was to use constrained_layout for matplotlib instead of 'tight' layout. I'd been trying to avoid 'constrained' since I thought it looked bad, but it turns out I was just applying it incorrectly.

As was mentioned in the comment, the issue is probably solved. However, you could suppress tight_layout warnings. Here is a solution that worked for me. No problems toggling between plots rapidly:
import random
import mplcursors
import customtkinter as ctk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, message=".*tight_layout.*")

window = ctk.CTk()
data_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(window)
button_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(window)
data_frame.pack(side=ctk.TOP)
button_frame.pack(side=ctk.BOTTOM)

lines = {}

fig = Figure(figsize=(13, 9), tight_layout=True)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=data_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=ctk.TOP, fill=ctk.BOTH, expand=True)
axes = fig.subplots(2, 2)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y = {}
y_new = {}
for i in range(1, 101):
    y[i] = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(len(x))]
    y_new[i] = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(len(x))]

show_y_new = ctk.BooleanVar(value=False)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(1, 101):
            line, = axes[i, j].plot(x, y[k], label=f'Line {k}')
            lines[line] = line

cursor = mplcursors.cursor(list(lines.keys()), hover=True)

def on_hover(sel):
    x, y = sel.target
    sel.annotation.set_text(f"({x:.2f}, {y:.2f})")

cursor.connect("add", on_hover)

def on_click(event):
    show_y_new.set(not show_y_new.get())
    if show_y_new.get():
        for line in lines:
            if line.axes == axes[1, 1]:
                line.set_ydata(y_new[int(line.get_label().split(' ')[1])])
    else:
        for line in lines:
            if line.axes == axes[1, 1]:
                line.set_ydata(y[int(line.get_label().split(' ')[1])])

    canvas.draw()
    cursor.update()

global button  
button_axes = fig.add_axes([0.8885, 0.467, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(button_axes, label='Toggle 1,1 data')
button.on_clicked(on_click)

exit_button = ctk.CTkButton(window, text='Exit', command=window.destroy)
exit_button.pack(side='bottom')  

canvas.draw()
window.mainloop()



